# Where to get the modern Constellations as a vector File?

Tags: data, vector

Does anyone know where I can get a vector version (shapefile/TAB) of the modern star constellations for the entire sky?

Wikipedia has a SVG - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Constellations_ecliptic_equirectangular_plot.svg - but I'd prefer not to have to try and convert it to a "proper" format.

Basically I want the below, but as a vector; ideally with the attribute data of constellation name for each polygon.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact the author of [this script](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=10656).  The link to the data ZIP on the script page doesn't work anymore.  If he replies, please post back here with a current link.

Comment: An oblique answer, but it worked. He shared this link with me: http://alpha.appgeo.com/astro/av_stars.zip -- `\av_stars\shapes\constell.shp` contains the constellations.

Comment: Just to make sure you know...  This is as if you are looking out towards the stars, not as if you are looking down onto a globe.  You can't lay this over a map of the world and say "England is in Cassiopeia".  Well, you could, but you would be wrong.  :)

Comment: Ah thanks. I'm not sure which is the desired option at present, but useful to know.